# Attempted to change outdoor light fixture and now no power

Tags: electrical, light

I decided to change an outdoor light fixture in front of my garage with a new one.

I made sure the light was off, but didn't turn the circuit breaker to off until I realized that I'd have to start messing with the wires coming out of the wall.

Once the circuit breaker was off, I removed the old fixture, noting that the wires were black to black, white to white, and copper to ground.

I installef the new light fixture in the same manner,  following instructions to put the wires in the caps and twist.

When I was done I flipped the circuit breaker back to on, but the power didn't come back on in the garage. I tried flipping on and off a few more times, including the master switch,  but still nothing.

Thinking that maybe the fuse in the circuit breaker was bad, I went out and bought a new one that wad the closest match that I could find. 15-15A.

I flipped the master switch to off, removed the old breaker and installed the new breaker, but still no power to the garage.

Since I uninstalled the new fixture, the wires are currently bare but I made sure they aren't touching.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: What make and model is the breaker box, and what make and model of replacement breaker did you use?  Does the breaker handle stay ON when switched ON, or does the handle not latch in the ON position?

Comment: When you were first installing the light with the power on, did you short some wires together, get sparks, flashes or noises like that?  Level with us, we need to know...

Comment: How many sets of wires are there in the outdoor box? Did you reconnect everything exactly as before?

Comment: Sounds like there might be another GFCI somewhere that will have tripped when you touched the wires

Comment: You need to go into a lot more detail about what switches you're flipping, where they are etc. Add pictures

Comment: With the power off, did you disconnect all the wires in the light fixture, then reattach them? It's quite easy to _think_ you've got them properly connected under the wire nut, but for them to not actually be properly connected, especially when connecting stranded lamp wire with solid house wire. Go shut off the breaker for this circuit and double check all your new fixture connections. After you've twisted a nut on, hold the nut and pull each wire to ensure it doesn't come loose.

Comment: I had to look up what a GFCI is, but I did find that there was one inside the garage that was tripped.

Comment: I had to look up what a GFCI is, but I did find that there was one inside the garage that was tripped. Since I had already uninstalled the new fixture, I went ahead and reset it and got power back to the garage. BUT, then I went and installed the new light fixture and it tripped the same GFCI again. I tried restting the GFCI with the new fixture installed and it would just re-trip right away. I uninstalled the new fixture and reinstalled the original, and all is back to normal. The new fixture says it should be installed on a line that is 60Hz and 120V, but that is what my breaker shows.

Comment: @Partdeux2 -- I'd take the new fixture back to where you got it from and complain that it has an internal ground fault problem, then -- it sounds like it's a QC reject that slipped through, and your GFCI is being kind enough to tell you about that fact before it bites you someday!